# codeigniter get array data in controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have sql query in controller, this query produces number of rows.

```
$q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT product_code,product_quantity FROM tbl_order_details WHERE order_id='$order_no' AND location='$location'")->row();

                 foreach($q1 as $v_barcode){
                 $result = $this->settings_model->update_cancel_stock($v_barcode->product_code,$v_barcode->product_quantity);
                 }
```

then i pass this data to my model,

```
public function update_cancel_stock($code,$qty)
    {

        $this->db->set('product_quantity', $qty , FALSE);
        $this->db->where('product_id', $order );
        $this->db->update("tbl_inventory6");                

    }
```

but no any update. please check above code. thanx

Answer (score 0):

You are using `row()` function of Active Record. It already return only one row. So there is no requirement of `foreach`. Try this:

```
$q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT product_code,product_quantity FROM tbl_order_details WHERE order_id='$order_no' AND location='$location'")->row();

$result = $this->settings_model->update_cancel_stock($q1->product_code,$q1->product_quantity);
```

If you are getting multiple records and you are using `foreach`, you should use `result()`.

```
$q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT product_code,product_quantity FROM tbl_order_details WHERE order_id='$order_no' AND location='$location'")->result();

foreach($q1 as $v_barcode){
    $result = $this->settings_model->update_cancel_stock($v_barcode->product_code,$v_barcode->product_quantity);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Akshay Prakash, I have removed ->row(); checked with the foreach, still not working.   $q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT product_code,product_quantity FROM tbl_order_details WHERE order_id='$order_no' AND location='$location'") ;
       foreach($q1 as $v_barcode){
$result = $this->settings_model->update_cancel_stock($v_barcode->product_code,$v_barcode->product_quantity);
    }

Comment: NO, I didn't mean that. If you remove `row()`, you will not be able to get the records. Codeigniter provides two functions - `row()` and `result()`. `row()` is used when you are getting just a row from your query. `result()` is used when you are getting more than one rows. So, without `row()`, the code would be as my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cond = array("order_id" => $order_no, "location" => $location);
$q1 = $this->db->select("product_code,product_quantity")->from("tbl_order_details")->where($cond)->row();

$result = $this->settings_model->update_cancel_stock($q1->product_code,$q1->product_quantity);
```

and then model (`$code` was not used)

```
public function update_cancel_stock($code,$qty){
     $this->db->set('product_quantity', $qty , FALSE);
     $this->db->where('product_id', $code);
     $this->db->update('tbl_inventory6');                
 }
```